# ¿Como hacer una expresion regular con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una clase en múltiples columnas, pero resulta que no me muestra la expresión regular, y me la deja los numeros en texto, debería de separarmelo por puntos, ¿como podría resolverlo?

**CODIGO**

```
$(".count").toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
```

Agradeceria el interes.

Comment: es decir lo que intentas hacer es aceptar solo decimales separados por punto ?

Comment: exacto, pero para aquellos campos que contienen la clase count